# Mobile navigation bar won't pull out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a mobile navigation menu, but for some odd reason, the code won't work. I feel like it's something with the css, but I'm not sure. I created a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c89jq7y1/3/) to play with it. I want the menu to open when you click the little button. The JavaScript must not be reading the request...

Java Script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("#hamburger").click(function () {

    jQuery('#content').css('min-height', jQuery(window).height());

    jQuery('nav').css('opacity', 1);
    var contentWidth = jQuery('#content').width();
    jQuery('#content').css('width', contentWidth);
    jQuery('#contentLayer').css('display', 'block');
    jQuery('#container').bind('touchmove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    jQuery("#container").animate({"marginLeft": ["70%", 'easeOutExpo']}, {
        duration: 700
    });
});
jQuery("#contentLayer").click(function () {
    jQuery('#container').unbind('touchmove');
    jQuery("#container").animate({"marginLeft": ["-1", 'easeOutExpo']}, {
        duration: 700,
        complete: function () {
            jQuery('#content').css('width', 'auto');
            jQuery('#contentLayer').css('display', 'none');
            jQuery('nav').css('opacity', 0);
            jQuery('#content').css('min-height', 'auto');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: works fine for me once I specify a jQuery library inside of JSFiddle.  I click on `#hamburger` and I see a menu appear.  what specifically is your problem?

Comment: I for whatever reason don't get the menu?

Comment: I want the menu to pull out from the side of the screen

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have jquery loaded in your jfiddle. When I loaded jQuery it worked for me.

Click on Javascript and then "FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS" and add jQuery 1.12 at least.

Comment: to be clear, you're asking a question about javascript, but you're using jQuery. so you must load the jQuery library to use it.